# How to annotate bar plots when adding error bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I have a dataframe dictionary like this

```
{'region': {0: 'R0',1: 'R1',2: 'R2',3: 'R3',4: 'R4',5: 'R5',6: 'R6'},
 'DT': {0: 0.765, 1: 0.694, 2: 0.778, 3: 0.694, 4: 0.629, 5: 0.67, 6: 0.668},
 'GB': {0: 0.714, 1: 0.741, 2: 0.752, 3: 0.741, 4: 0.683, 5: 0.706, 6: 0.656},
 'KNN': {0: 0.625, 1: 0.641, 2: 0.628, 3: 0.641, 4: 0.552, 5: 0.544, 6: 0.578},
 'LR': {0: 0.624, 1: 0.662, 2: 0.634, 3: 0.662, 4: 0.581, 5: 0.629, 6: 0.649},
 'lstm': {0: 0.803,1: 0.633,2: 0.845,3: 0.668,4: 0.717,5: 0.726,6: 0.674}}
```

In neat format

```
    region DT   GB      KNN      LR     lstm
0   R0  0.765   0.714   0.625   0.624   0.803
1   R1  0.694   0.741   0.641   0.662   0.633
2   R2  0.778   0.752   0.628   0.634   0.845
3   R3  0.694   0.741   0.641   0.662   0.668
4   R4  0.629   0.683   0.552   0.581   0.717
5   R5  0.67    0.706   0.544   0.629   0.726
6   R6  0.668   0.656   0.578   0.649   0.674
```

I want to plot stacked bar graph with error bar. This dataframe dont have information about standard deviation, but i have another dataframe of standard deviation.

Suppose there are two dataframe mean, and std

I tried this code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width=0.5
clfs=['DT', 'KNN', 'LR', 'GB', 'lstm']
ax.bar(mean_df['region'], mean_df[clfs[0]], width,yerr=std_df[clfs[0]], label=clfs[0])
for i in range(1,5):
    ax.bar(mean_df['region'], mean_df[clfs[i]], width,yerr=std_df[clfs[i]], label=clfs[i],bottom=mean_df[clfs[i-1]])

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but the bars are not being stacked properly. I am also looking a way to write value on each bar segment to increase the readability of plot
[image]

EDIT:
Solution is to add first two list in bottom while plotting third one.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(mean_df['region'], mean_df[clfs[0]], width,yerr=std_df[clfs[0]], label=clfs[0])
ax.bar(mean_df['region'], mean_df[clfs[1]], width,yerr=std_df[clfs[1]], label=clfs[1],bottom=mean_df[clfs[0]])
ax.bar(mean_df['region'], mean_df[clfs[2]], width,yerr=std_df[clfs[2]], label=clfs[2],
       bottom=mean_df[clfs[0]]+mean_df[clfs[1]])
```

But i am looking for an elegant way to do this and also how to write  values on segment of bar

EDIT 2:
I came to this

```
ax = mean_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6),yerr=std_df, rot=0, xlabel='region', ylabel='DT')
```

But now i am looking way to write text.
I tried this

```
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
```

but i got this error

```
AttributeError: 'ErrorbarContainer' object has no attribute 'patches'
```

EDIT 3
This error is because of `yerr=std_df`, but i also want to keep error bars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Stacked bars are not an ideal way to present the data. With error bars, stacked bars are even more difficult to read, may overlap with the error bar within a given stack, and with the annotations, which can lead to a confusing visualization.
- The issue will occur for `stacked=True` or `stacked=False`, and it applies to using [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) followed by [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html).

  - This answer also applies to horizontal bars.
  - **This does not apply to seaborn barplots with `ci=True`**
- `pandas.DataFrame.plot` returns an `Axes`, from which `containers` can be extracted.

  - Adding `yerr` results in the `containers` containing `ErrorbarContainer object` and `BarContainer object`
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for a thorough explanation of using [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) with additional examples.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### `ax.containers`

```
[<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>,
 <BarContainer object of 2 artists>,
 <ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>,
 <BarContainer object of 2 artists>,
 <ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>,
 <BarContainer object of 2 artists>]
```

- `.bar_label` will annotate with the patch value when using `label_type='center'`, and the cumsum of the patches when using `label_type='edge'`

### `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with `yerr`

- The `BarContainer` objects are at the odd indices, which can be extracted with `ax.containers[1::2]`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# load same dataframe
pen = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

# create the aggregated dataframe (mean)
pen_mean = pen.pivot_table(index='sex', columns='species', values='bill_depth_mm', aggfunc='mean')

# create the dataframe for the error bars with (std)
pen_std = pen.pivot_table(index='sex', columns='species', values='bill_depth_mm', aggfunc='std')

# plot the dataframe and add yerr
ax = pen_mean.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(9, 6), rot=0, yerr=pen_std)

# move the legend
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')

# iterate through every other container; the even containers are ErrorbarContainer
for c in ax.containers[1::2]:

    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
```

[image]

#### Horizontal Bars

```py
# plot the dataframe and add yerr
ax = pen_mean.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(9, 6), rot=0, xerr=pen_std)

# move the legend
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')

# iterate through every other container; the even containers are ErrorbarContainer
for c in ax.containers[1::2]:

    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
```

[image]

---

### `Axes.bar` with `Axes.errorbar`

- The BarContainer objects are at the even indices, which can be extracted with `ax.containers[0::2]`

```py
data = pen_mean

cols = pen_mean.columns
rows = pen_mean.index

# Get some pastel shades for the colors
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:green']
n_rows = len(data)

index = np.arange(len(cols))
bar_width = 0.4

# Initialize the vertical-offset for the stacked bar chart.
y_offset = np.zeros(len(cols))

# Plot bars and create text labels for the table
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    ax.bar(cols, data.loc[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[i])
    ax.errorbar(cols, y_offset+data.loc[row], pen_std.loc[row], color='k', ls='none')
    y_offset = y_offset + data.loc[row]
    
# note the order of the container objects is different
for c in ax.containers[0::2]:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### seaborn bars

- seaborn bar plots with the default `ci=True` do not return `ErrorbarContainer objects` in `containers`.

#### `sns.catplot` with `kind='bar'`

- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67594395/7758804) for an additional example of annotating a seaborn figure-level bar plot.

```py
p = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=pen, x='sex', y='bill_depth_mm', hue='species', height=4.5, aspect=1.5)

# since this is a single subplot of a figure
ax = p.axes.flat[0]

for c in ax.containers:

    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
```

[image]

#### `sns.barplot`

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
p = sns.barplot(data=pen, x='sex', y='bill_depth_mm', hue='species')

p.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')

for c in p.containers:

    # add the annotation
    p.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
```

[image]