# How can I create a bar chart in the image attached to the question?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I would like to create a subplot of bar chart where '% of total' is the y-axis and 'plants' is the x-axis. Also 'brand' will be legend, so in this case 3 different charts for the 3 different 'brands'. Each groups % adds up to 100%. I started with the code below, but got stuck. Please see a sample of the data below and image below;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand':['A','A', 'A', 'B','B', 'B' ,'C','C', 'C'],
    'plants':[0, 1, 2, 0,1,2,0,1,2],
    '% of total':[80, 12, 8, 67, 18, 5,35, 40,25],
    
    })

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i, brand in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C']):
```

[image]

Comment: `sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', x='plants', y='% of total', col='brand')`

Comment: Use the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67594395/15239951) of @TrentonMcKinney +1

Comment: With only pandas: 1. `dfp = df.pivot(index='plants', columns='brand', values='% of total')` 2. `dfp.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, rot=0, layout=(1, 3), figsize=(12, 5), legend=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `seaborn` and [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
# Python env: pip install seaborn
# Anaconda env: conda install seaborn
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.catplot(x='plants', y='% of total', col='brand', data=df, kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be in a for loop? You could simply grab the relevant rows using pandas.

For example:

```
my_A_df = df[df['brand'] == A]
plt.hist(my_A_df)
plt.bar(my_A_df['plants'], my_A_df['% of total'])
```

This will work for generating a barplot for each. Not sure if this is within the bounds of your problem but happy to edit if necessary.